# Generate Timestamp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, datetime, timestamp

I am getting a timestamp value in an xml request as the following format.

```
2014-06-27T12:41:13.0000617Z
```

I need to form the xml response with this kind of time format in ruby. How do I get this format for the corresponding time?

I wanted to know the name of this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
t = Time.utc(2010,3,30, 5,43,"25.123456789".to_r)
t.iso8601(10)
```

This produces:

```
"2010-03-30T05:43:25.1234567890Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

datetime = DateTime.parse('2014-06-27T12:41:13.0000617Z')
repr = datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%7NZ')
puts repr
#=> 2014-06-27T12:41:13.0000617Z
```